# what would happen to humans if the earth slowed down and finally stopped?

Tags: earth

my question is if the earth slowed down what would happen to humans would we die would some of us die would we all live what would happen?
I have tried google and that did not work is there any thing you guys would recommend?

Comment: Does https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38317/if-the-earth-gradually-stopped-spinning-what-would-the-changes-look-like-in-20?rq=1 answer you questions?

Comment: In short? Tidally locked planets can't support life

Comment: Depends on how fast. It's not the slowdown that kills you, it's the sudden stop.

Comment: @Trish That remains to be determined, and in any case it depends on *what* the planet is tidally locked to.

Answer (score 2):

If you were asking what would happen if the Earth slowed down in its orbit around the Sun, the answer is the Earth would fall towards the Sun. If it stopped totally it would fall right into the Sun and be destroyed utterly with in around 65 days.

If it only slowed but did not stop, it would end up in a much more eccentric orbit around the Sun. Anything more than a very slight slowing would probably make Earth uninhabitable as it would be super heated at closest approach each year.